# status: 415, error: "Unsupported Media Type" - Reactjs for POST request

Tags: java, reactjs, post, http-post

I am trying to make a POST request through reactjs, but I am getting an error. The same code for GET is working fine.

The error is:

> status: 415, error: "Unsupported Media Type", exception: "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",

Here is my reactjs code:

```
import React from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
const style = {
 margin: 15,
marginLeft: 600
};
export default class  Register extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.onSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
handleSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var self = this;
   const payload = {
   id: self.refs.id.getValue(),
   studentName: self.refs.sname.getValue(),
   age: self.refs.age.getValue(),
   emailId: self.refs.emailId.getValue()
};
   var data = new FormData();
data.append("myjsonkey", JSON.stringify(payload));

fetch('http://localhost:8083/students', {
   method: 'POST',
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   body: data
 })
   .then(function(response) {
       return response.json()
     }).then(function(body) {
       console.log(body);
     });
 }

render() {
   return (
     <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
     <div style={style}>
     <TextField ref='id'
     hintText="Enter Student id"
     floatingLabelText="id"
     />
     <br/>
     <TextField ref='sname'
     hintText="Enter your Last Name"
     floatingLabelText="StudentName"
     />
     <br/>
     <TextField ref='age'
     hintText="Enter your Age"
     floatingLabelText="age"
     />
     <br/>

     <TextField ref='emailId'
     hintText="Enter your Email"
     floatingLabelText="emailId"
     />
     <br/>
     <br/>
     <input type="submit" />
     </div>
         </form>

   );
 }
}
```

Comment: The error message is telling you what the problem is. 415 means, as it says, "Unsupported media type". Your server doesn't support the media type that you are specifying in your request. You need to either make the server support it, or provide a different media type in your request.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave i understand the problem meaning,but i dont know where and what i have to change. So could you please suggest me.